# CentOS - You must give (non-root) uid and gid

Tags: centos6, ftp

I'm trying to add users to ftp using `pure-ftp`

I used the following command:

`pure-pw useradd test-user -u ftpgroup -d /path/to/my/dir`

And I get the following error:

`You must give (non-root) uid and gid`

Is there anything I can do to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You need to give a -u uid and -g gid.

`pure-pw useradd test-user -u 1234 -g 1234 -d /path/to/my/dir`

Obviously use your own numbers...

Comment: Is 1234 a user? i.e. one that has been created by `useradd 1234` and `passwd 1234`?

Comment: No, uid is a numeric ID of the user. And gid is a numeric ID relating to the group.

Answer (score 3):

Or find the numbers as explained in [this article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/adwf)

To find a user's UID or GID in Unix, use the id command. To find a specific user's UID, at the Unix prompt, enter:

```
id -u username
```

Replace username with the appropriate user's username. To find a user's GID, at the Unix prompt, enter:

```
id -g username
```

If you wish to find out all the groups a user belongs to, instead enter:

```
id -G username
```

If you wish to see the UID and all groups associated with a user, enter id without any options, as follows:

```
id username
```